# My perl comparison script is failing while running on huge txt files can any one help out on performance improvement

Tags: perl

Right now the above script is able to compare around 9GB to 10GBfiles. But I wanted to compare with very big files like more than 50GB. While running my script it has been killed automatically. Can anyone help how to improve the performance to compare such big files with my script.

Here is my code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Std;
use FileHandle;

open STDOUT, ">", "output.txt" or die "$0: open: $!";
my %opts;
my $optstr = "i:o:";
getopts("$optstr", \%opts);
if($opts{i} eq '' || $opts{o} eq '' )
{
        print "usage: perl TextCompare_Fund.pl <-i INPUTFILE> <-o MAPREDUCE OUTPUTFILE>\n";
        die 1;
}
my $inputFilesPath=$opts{i};
my $outputFilesPath=$opts{o};
my @ifiles=`ls $inputFilesPath`;
my @ofiles=`ls $outputFilesPath`;
foreach my $ifile (@ifiles)
{
    my $ifile_substr=substr("$ifile",0,-25);
    foreach my $ofile (@ofiles)
    {
        my $ofile_substr=substr("$ofile",0,-25);
        my $result=$ifile_substr cmp $ofile_substr;
        if($result eq 0)
        {
            #print "$result\n";
            #print "$ifile\n";
            compare($ifile,$ofile)
        }
    }
}
sub compare
{
    my $afile="$_[0]";
    my $bfile="$_[1]";
    my $path1="$inputFilesPath/$afile";
    my $path2="$outputFilesPath/$bfile";
    chomp $path1;
    chomp $path2;
    #open FILE, "<", $path1 or die "$!:$path1";
    open my $infile, "<", $path1 or die "Couldn't open $path1: $!";
    my %a_lines;
    my %b_lines;
    my $count1=0;
    while (my $line = <$infile>) 
    {
        chomp $line;
            $a_lines{$line} = undef;
        $count1=$count1+1;
    }
    print"$bfile records count : $count1\n";
    close $infile;
    my $file=substr("$afile",0,-25);
    my $OUTPUT = "/hadoop/user/m6034690/Kishore/CompareResult_Files/$file.comparision_result";
    open my $outfile, "<", $path2 or die "Couldn't open $path2: $!";
    open (OUTPUT, ">$OUTPUT") or die "Cannot open $OUTPUT \n";

    my $count=0;
    my $count2=0;
    while (my $line = <$outfile>) 
    {
        chomp $line;
        $b_lines{$line} = undef;
        $count2=$count2+1;
        next if exists $a_lines{$line};
        $count=$count+1;
        print OUTPUT "$line \t===> The Line which is selected from file2/arg2 is mismatching/not available in file1\n";
    }   
    print "$bfile records count : $count2\n";
    print "Total mismatching/unavailable records in file1 : $count\n";
    close $outfile;
    close OUTPUT;
}
close (STDOUT);
```

Comment: What is the format of the input files? How much memory does your machine have?

Comment: SO you out trying to to identify the lines in file2 that aren't in file1?

Comment: @nmkishore as mentioned in the other question, we just need to read the lines 1 by one and not store everything in memory, I will write an answer now.

Comment: So… this is a Perl question about working with really big files in an environment where it appears Hadoop is running. Could you have used Hadoop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're loading the entire file into memory. Obviously, that's a no-go.

So you out trying to to identify the lines in file2 that aren't in file1? That can be done with no memory if the files are sorted. So start by sorting the files. The unix `sort` utility can handle files of arbitrary size, so let's use that.

```
diff -u <( sort -u file1 ) <( sort -u file2 ) | tail -n +3 | grep ^+ | cut -c 2-
```

or

```
sub compare {
   my ($qfn1, $qfn2) = @_;

   open(my $fh1, '-|', 'sort', '-u', '--', $qfn1) or die $!;
   open(my $fh2, '-|', 'sort', '-u', '--', $qfn2) or die $!;

   my $line1 = <$fh1>;
   my $line2 = <$fh2>;
   while ($line1 && $line2) {
      my $cmp = $line1 cmp $line2;
      print($line2) if $cmp > 0;
      $line1 = <$fh1> if $cmp <= 0;
      $line2 = <$fh2> if $cmp >= 0;
   }

   while ($line2) {
      print($line2);
      $line2 = <$fh2>;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you're processing a Hadoop environment's output and worried about files that are too large to process with Perl on a single machine. Luckily Hadoop gives you an environment to use multiple-machines (or not) for your problem. They call it [Hadoop Streaming](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current3/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html).

So, if you made a mapper that mapped all input lines to a file name, you could run multiple such mappers over multiple files or file splits, producing something like:

```
# key \t value
lineA \t file1
lineB \t file1
lineC \t file1
lineA \t file2
lineC \t file2
…
```

A set of reducers could then run to reduce the results. Mappers hash the keys to determine which reducer the key value pair will be sent to, so any number of reducers which append values together should produce the correct intermediate representation like:

```
# key \t value-reduced
lineA \t file1 , file2
lineB \t file1
lineC \t file1 , file2
```

This can be stored to multiple files in a hdfs directory if the line itself is stored with the value. That could be mapped with Hive to a table where you could query just the lines you're interested in using SQL syntax. Or you could run another mapper(s) over all this input to drop lines you're not interested in (only in file2?, in both files? in all files (you could be handling more files)).

All of this could be implemented using the [hadoop-streaming](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html) (a.ka. plain-text) interface, and perl/python/bash. Though honestly implementing it perfectly is not something I have time for right here & now.
The input file name is available in the [job conf variables](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html#Configured+Parameters).

There's a way to split inputs by size to mappers. The default input format TextInputFormat supports it for uncompressed text. However I can't find the right document about the property you might set to choose to keep the splits to say 256mb or what have you.

As you might imagine, due to the input line containing almost any (utf-8?) values, you might want to change the default Key Value separator too; that's in the previously linked docs. Lots of people use the Start of Heading 0x01 or Vertical Tab 0x0B.